# Cannot call JQuery plugin from Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs, sticky

I try to call a JQuery sticky plugin from the following declaration, but nothing happen i have check with debug message it pass through the line and the sticky not appear. But its Ok when i call normally from somewhere else.

```
var globalService = angular.module('global.service', []);
globalService.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('myHttpInterceptor');
    var spinnerFunction = function (data, headersGetter) {
        var settings = {
                'speed' : 'fast',
                'duplicates' : false,
                'autoclose' : false
        };

        $.sticky('Loading..', settings);
        return data;
    };
    $httpProvider.defaults.transformRequest.push(spinnerFunction);
});

//register the interceptor as a service, intercepts ALL angular ajax http calls
globalService.factory('myHttpInterceptor', function ($q, $window) {
    return function (promise) {
        return promise.then(function (response) {
            // do something on success
            // todo hide the spinner

            $.sticky.clear();
            return response;

        }, function (response) {
            // do something on error
            // todo hide the spinner

            $.sticky.clear();
            return $q.reject(response);
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. It was error on `$.sticky.clear()`, i have made a correction.

Comment: Consider deleting this question, or adding your comment as an answer, so that this question no longer shows up on the "unanswered" list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code above works fine after fixing $.sticky.clear()